# KDE won't automount dvd on CentOS

Tags: centos, kde-plasma, automount

This is driving me crazy. I have CentOS 5.5 installed running KDE desktop. I have an NEC 3550 DVDRW drive on **/dev/hda**. When I put in a DVD, I want it to automount it and provide an icon on the desktop, as well as under /media mount point.  It will not automount.  Automount is running. HALD is running.  Drive is on /dev/hda.  It is NOT listed in /etc/fstab.  There is NOT a remove policy setup for hald-addon-storage for polling.  I can read from the drive using dd.  K3B burn utility can see the drive and read disk info.  Running **eject** and **eject -t** ejects the drive ok.
I cannot mount from the command line. Says:

```
mount: block device /dev/hda is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/hda,
       missing codepage or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

dmesg says:

```
ide: failed opcode was: unknown
ATAPI device hda:
  Error: Illegal request -- (Sense key=0x05)
  Cannot read medium - incompatible format -- (asc=0x30, ascq=0x02)
  The failed "Read Subchannel" packet command was:
  "42 02 40 01 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 "
hfs: unable to parse mount options
attempt to access beyond end of device
hda: rw=0, want=68, limit=4
isofs_fill_super: bread failed, dev=hda, iso_blknum=16, block=16
```

To me, seems like some kind of media format issue, but I have no idea. Ideas?

Comment: Belongs to superuser.com. As far as I know, you can only mouny partitions, not a whole block device. Try `/dev/hda1` instead.

Comment: [root@dev ~]# mount -t iso9660 /dev/hda1 /media
mount: special device /dev/hda1 does not exist

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I tried it again, and now it works. I wish I could post the solution here, but I don't know what it was. I am sorry. Maybe I have flaky hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no real solution, started working on its own.